# show listdata in react as divider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, semantic-ui-react

i am work with react semantic form control, i want used divider in my select case , or also used react list,but there is not added or how to extract value of list, i want to show value as divider

code:

```
let permissions = [
      { key: 1, value: 1, text: 'Owner',msg:'Can fully configure and edit anything, manage workspaces and billing' },
      { key: 2, value: 2, text: 'Creator',msg:'Can completely configure a stack' },
      { key: 3, value: 3, text: 'Editor',msg:'Can only edit rows, cannot configure tables or columns' },
      { key: 4, value: 4, text: 'Commenter',msg:'Can only comment on rows' },
      { key: 5, value: 5, text: 'Read only',msg:'Cannot edit anything, only read' }
    ];

    this.state = {
      permissions,
    }

      <Form.Select width={4} style={{border:'2px solid #2185d0'}}
               placeholder='*Permission'
               className="OnMobileView"
               options={permissions} />
```

i want display **text** and **msg**  on select-case, but i dont know how to get this, i want this type of output

[image]

Comment: Are you using Semantic-ui?

Comment: @antoineso    yes  i will used react-semantic